# What is the best topology for this odd shape?

Tags: mesh

[image: Existing mesh]

The existing mesh works, but its a mess, not a mesh ;-)

Comment: Unless you need further modelling or UV Unwrapping bezier curves sound like the obvious choice, so you don't even have to worry about topology at all

Comment: Could you upload image of this shape? Or even blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: got  some suggestions, can you give topview, or reference image?

Answer (score 6):

### Version 1: Low poly.

This is topology which is focused on small amount of polygons. **Edge Flows** aren't so good and using **Proximity Loops** will be pretty hard, but nevertheless both methods are working best with **Bevel Modifier** (Angle) + **Subdivision Surface**.

**Topology:**

[image: low_poly]

**Result:**

[image: low_poly result]

### Version 2: Edge Flow.

This method is focused on proper **Edge Flows**. You can use here **Proximity Loops** to sharpen edges but as stated in *Version 1* it's better to use modifiers.

Here we need to use two ngons to stop inner loops before 'big circle'.

**Topology:**

[image: loops]

**Result:**

[image: loops_final]

### How to make it.

I will not create whole step-by-step answer here as methods used was just Blender 101 modeling. I've started with outer **Circle** then created another one in the middle, scale it to have egg shape and from there it was just manual Extruding, Moving, Joining etc. I've also used two add-ons here: **LoopTools** > Space and **F2** to speed up my work. They both are built in in Blender, you will just need to turn them on.

### Notes.

My model is pretty uneven as I was modeling it 'by hand' with distorted reference image. If you have good .svg shape, you can import it and use it edges to snap vertices to them.

### Blend file.

Here is my blend file. You can check different layers for both versions, also you will be able to see detailed values for modifier I've used.

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer.  Out of curiosity, is there a modelling reason for finishing the inner loop with ngons?  Is it just for segment symmetry?

Comment: @bertmoog this ngon is forced by two loops on those 'wings' part of the mesh. In Version 1 one triangle is stopping edge loop from going on to the outer circle. In this situation it was only thing I could make out of it and letting loop to go further would 'break' smoothness of this outer circle.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that this is *the best* topology, but I'd probably go for something like this:
[image: Spiral thingy topology]